# Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $f(x)=x^p-a\in F[x].$ Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ or $f(x)$ splits in $F.$

Tags: field-theory

Let $F$ be a field of characteristic $p$ and let $f(x)=x^p-a\in F[x].$ Show that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ or $f(x)$ splits in $F.$

Please help me. I'm absolutely clueless.

Comment: Is $F$ a finite field ?

Comment: Please avoid putting the whole question in the title. That's what the body is for.

Comment: Being clueless is normal: this is a difficult result.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwaig I will try the case $p=5$

Comment: Dear @Amr: are you user144258?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg No. ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Amr: thanks for answering. I asked because you are so enthusiastic about the question: which is all to your credit!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Suppose theres a root $\;\omega\in F\;$ of $\;f(x)\;$, so $\;\omega^p=a\;$,  but then

$$ x^p-a=(x-\omega)^p =\;\ldots$$

Comment: Hi I dont get the hint.

Comment: @Amr , in characteristic $\;p>0\;$ , the freshman's dream becomes true: $\;(a+b)^p=a^p+b^p\;$ ...

Comment: I know this, but why does $f$ reducible imply that it has a root

Comment: I suppose you are assuming that f is reducilbe (because it its irreducible we are done), now how do we deduce that $f$ has a root

Comment: @Amr, what I show (well, hint...but almost)  is that **if** the pol. has a root then it splits in linear factors...if it doesn't then we still must argue why we can't write $\;f(x)=h(x)g(x)\;$ and etc.

Comment: By the way, if $p$ is a prime number and $F$ is a field of **arbitrary  characteristic** (for example characteristic zero) the polynomial $x^p-a\in F[x]$ is irreducible as soon as it has no root in $F$.

Comment: I am unable to see immediately why $f$ is reducible implies that $f$ has a root in $F$. But, I will try to prove it.

Comment: For $p\in \{2,3\}$, I am able to see this. I will try now the case $p=5$

Comment: I didn't know about @GeorgesElencwajg's claim in full generality, but here's a hint that works as long as $x^p-1$ splits in $F$, as it does in characteristic $p$: Show that the prime factorization of $x^p-a \in F[x]$ must be into irreducible polynomials of equal degree, by showing that every root of $x^p-a$ generates the same extension over $F$.

Answer (score 5):

**Theorem (Capelli)**
Let $p$ be a prime and $F$ be a field of any characteristic.
If the polynomial $x^p-a\in F[x]$ has no root in $F$, then it is irreducible.

**Proof when $F$ is of characteristic $p$ ( the case actually asked by the OP)**
Let $\alpha$ be a root of $x^p-a$ in a splitting field $K$ of that polynomial, so that $x^p-a=(x-\alpha)^p\in K[x]$,  and let $f(x)=Irr(\alpha, F,x)$ be the (irreducible !) minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $F$.
Then $f(x)$ divides $x^p-a$ (in $F[x]$ or $K[x]$) and so is of the form $(x-\alpha)^r$ with $1\leq r\leq p$, as is any divisor of $x^p-a=(x-\alpha)^p$ .
But since $f(x)\in F[x]$, we have $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^r=x^r-r\alpha x^{r-1}+\cdots \in F[x]$ so that $r\alpha\in F$ which [since $1\leq r\leq p$ and $\alpha\notin F$] is only possible if $r=p$.
But this means that $f(x)=(x-\alpha)^r=(x-\alpha)^p=x^p-a$ and so $x^p-a$ is indeed irreducible since $f(x)$ , being a minimal polynomial, is irreducible.

**Proof (much more difficult) when $F$ is not of characteristic $p$**
Lang, [Algebra](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebra.html?id=Fge-BwqhqIYC&redir_esc=y) Chapter VI, §9, Theorem 9.1  .

Answer (score 2):

The following should be considered a long comment. I will answer your question in case $F$ is a finite field. Using Don Antonio's answer, it suffices to show that $x^p-a$ is reducible implies that it has a root in $F$. Consider $\phi:F\rightarrow F$ that sends $x$ to $x^p$. One verifies easily that  $f$ is a ring homomorphism. One also verifies easily that $Ker(f)$ is trivial, thus $f$ is injective. Since our field is finite, therefore $f$ is surjective. Thus, there exists $w\in F$ such that $w^p=a$.

Note: The above argument shows that $x^p-a$ always has root (hence always reducible) in case $F$ is finite and $Char(F)=p$

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg I put something trivial here :)

Comment: Dear Amr: it's a special case , but it is definitely not trivial nor just a comment. Especially if you have never heard of the Frobenius map, which you then have rediscovered :-) Anyway, +1

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $F$
and let $r$ be a root of $f(x)$ in $E$.
Then $f(r)=r^p-a=0$ and $r^p=a$ and $f(x)=x^p-a=x^p-r^p=(x-r)^p$ by $char F=p$ and Freshman's Dream.

**Case I**: If $r\in F$,
then $f(x)=(x-r)^p$ splits in $F[x]$.

**Case II**: If $r\notin F$.
Since $F[x]$ is a UFD,
suppose that $f(x)=g_1(x)g_2(x)\cdots g_n(x)$,
where $g_i(x)$ is irreducible and monic in $F[x]$ for each $i=1, 2, ..., n$.
(Note that $f(x)$ is monic.)
In addition,
$\deg{g_i(x)}\geq 2$ for each $i=1, 2, ..., n$.
For if $\deg{g_i(x)}=1$,
then $g_i(x)=(x-s)\in F[x]$
and $s\in F$ is a root of $f(x)$.
Which is the Case I.

Then we have $f(x)=g_1(x)g_2(x)\cdots g_n(x)=(x-r)^p$.
For each $i=1, 2, ..., n$,
since $\deg{g_i(x)}\geq 2$,
it follows that $g_i(x)$ has multiple root in $E$.
Recall that $g_i(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.
Which implies that $g_i(x)=h_i(x^p)$ for some $h_i(x)\in F[x]$.
(Here I use a theorem.)
Then $f(x)=x^p-a=h_1(x^p)h_2(x^p)\cdots h_n(x^p)$.
Compare the degree of this equation,
it must be $\deg{h_1(x)}=1$ and $h_2(x), h_3(x), ..., h_n(x)$ all are constant.
It follows that $g_2(x)=g_3(x)=\cdots =g_n(x)=1$ and $g_1(x)=f(x)$.
Therefore, $f(x)=g_1(x)$ is irreducible over $F$.

This question appears at the Gallian's *Contemporary Abstract Algebra* 8/e (Exercise 20.15).

Comment: since $h_{i}(x)$ are constants then $g_{i}(x)$ are units for $i=2,...,n$. This implies that $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$