# If a polynomial $g$ divides $f$ and $f'$, then $g^2$ divides $f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, field-theory

Here's a homework problem from Artin's Algebra that I'm having a lot of trouble with

> Let $f(x) \in F[x]$ (where $F$ is a field of characteristic $0$).  If $g$ is an irreducible polynomial that is a common divisor $f$ and $f'$, then $g^2$ divides $f$ (where $f'$ denotes the derivative of $f$ in $F[x]$).

Let $K$ be an extension of $F$ such that $f$ splits completely in $K$.  So we can write $f(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n (x - \alpha_i)$ for some $\alpha_i \in K$.  Because $g$ divides $f$ in $F[x]$, we know that $g$ divides $f$ in $K[x]$.  Since $g$ divides $f$ we can write $g(x) = \prod_{j=1}^m (x - \alpha_{i_j})$.  Because $g$ is a common divisor of $f$ and $f'$, the roots $\alpha_i$ have some multiplicity greater than $1$, so that $(x - \alpha_i)^2$ divide $f$ for each $i$ (**).  Then $g^2$ divides $f$.

I think this is the right idea, although it feels like there are some holes in the argument (specifically the sentence marked with (**) at the end).  I also don't think I used the assumption that $g$ is irreducible.  Does this look OK?

Answer (score 5):

You need to be much more careful with the (**) step.  Specifically what if there are repeated roots?  For example $f = (x - 1)^3$ and $g = (x - 1)^2$ would break your argument.  Of course that's not a counterexample to the theorem because the $g$ I listed isn't irreducible.

I think passing to a field extension is more complicated than this proof needs to be.  My suggestion is to start by saying $f = gk$ and then take the derivative of $f$ using the product rule.  You'll want to eventually conclude that $g$ divides $k$ so that then $g^2$ divides $f$.

Answer (score 4):

There are already good answers to the actual question but let me show why characteristic zero is required for the exercise.

Let $F$ be an imperfect field of characteristic $p\gt 0$ and let $a\in F$ be an element which is not the $p$-th power of an element of $F$: in other words $a\in F\setminus F^p$.
The polynomial $f(x)=g(x)=x^p-a\in F[x]$ is then irreducible (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/760982/3217)) .
But although $g$ divides $f$ (since $g=f$) and also divides $f'$ (since $f'=0$), $g^2=f^2$ does not divide $f$: the statement in the exercise fails in positive characteristic.

Answer (score 3):

Derive the relation $f(x) = g(x) k(x)$.
Then, observe that the polynomials $g$ and $g'$ are relatively prime (since $g$ is irreducible).

Comment: "...since $g$ is irreducible" **and $char.F=0$**

Answer (score 2):

Since $g(x)$ divides $f(x)$, one has $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ for some $h(x)$. Taking derivatives, one has 
$$f'(x) = g'(x)h(x) + g(x)h'(x)$$

Since $g(x)$ divides $f'(x)$, it divides $f'(x) - g(x)h'(x) = g'(x)h(x)$. Since $g(x)$ is irreducible, it is prime, so since it divides $g'(x)h(x)$ it must divide $g'(x)$ or $h(x)$.

But $g'(x)$ is of lower degree than $g(x)$, so $g(x)$ must divide $h(x)$. Hence $f(x) = g(x)h(x) = g(x)^2p(x)$ for some polynomial $p(x)$.

Comment: You did not answer his question.

Comment: Sometimes a simpler answer to the original question is better.

Comment: Not when the question is "have I made a mistake".  By not addressing that you just do an end run around their learning process and they don't benefit.  It's the laziest way possible to pretend to give help.

Comment: His approach is unnecessarily complicated, and I do not believe it should be encouraged. By doing so, you are encouraging him to 1) waste time and 2) look at the problem in a bad way. Furthermore, once he realizes this approach works, he will not pursue his original approach anyhow.

Comment: You don't have to encourage it to point out what's wrong with it, and figuring out your mistakes is never a waste of time.  For shame.

Comment: his mistake was his original approach

Comment: And god forbid you take a second to explain why, by pointing out where his original method has a gap.  Because as you said, if the original method is correct then why do it differently?

Comment: People have different ideas on how to answer questions. I saw someone who was thinking hard in the wrong way, so I gave a different method. In retrospect I should have given fewer details so he could figure out the rest. It's not up to you to decide how others choose to help, old man.

Comment: And it's not up to you to decide how others comment on your help, or to make rude personal comments.  For shame.

Comment: You can comment all you want, feel free. You won't change my mind however :)

Comment: I don't need to change your mind, I just need there to be a record of why it's a bad answer, and there is. :)

Comment: Dear @Jim, Zarrax has written an excellent and complete answer to Artin's exercise. It will be useful to the OP and other users. Your answer is quite interesting too  and has rightfully been strongly upvoted . There is however no need to be unduly critical, and there is ample place for both answers on this site.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, it is not unduly critical to ask that an answer address the question that was actually asked.  And there absolutely should not be room on this site for rude personal comments.

Comment: Looking at the answers, I can see that passing to an extension is too complicated for the problem.  The only reason I thought of that is because this question comes from the section talking about adjoining roots of polynomials and field extensions (I don't like how Artin often gives questions that use little / nothing from the section they are assigned from).

Comment: Dear @Jim:  I certainly agree that there is no room on this site for rude personal remarks (quite independently of the thread here, about which I'd prefer not to contribute any more).